# Bigquery using case when for different datatypes in the same column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, case, gcloud

I have column that has both integers and timestamp in a single column. I am trying to check with case when and if the datatype is integer I want to use Timestamp_seconds to cast it if not I want to use the default value.

```
SELCT
  CASE WHEN  CAST(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(payload, '$.job.created_at') AS INT64) IS NOT NULL 
       THEN TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(CAST(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(payload, '$.job.created_at') AS INT64))  
  END AS job_created_timestamp FROM tableA ;
```

is giving Bad int64 value: 2020-10-28T02:15:35.666Z for values that are not integers. And I tried many options like IS TRUE ,ELSE for case when and nothing seems to work. Please let me know for any thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: Try using SAFE_CAST

Comment: Yeah was going to second that, you can use SAFE_CAST then it will return nulls instead of errors. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#safe_casting

Comment: I actually used the case statement to separate out Int64 and timestamp values in a With clause and then merged them in the select statement using  COALESCE(temp.integer_timestamp,temp.timestamp,NULL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround is this :

Use case statement to separate out Int64 and timestamp values of a column in a With clause(as separate columns) and then merge them in the select statement using COALESCE(temp.integer_timestamp,temp.timestamp,NULL)

Answer (score 0):

Posting @NickW's recommendation as answer for a better visibility for the community.

Using [`SAFE_CAST`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#safe_casting) instead of `CAST` function to replace the errors with null values instead.

> If you want to protect your queries from these types of errors, you can use SAFE_CAST. SAFE_CAST replaces runtime errors with NULLs. However, during static analysis, impossible casts between two non-castable types still produce an error because the query is invalid.